# Strengthening Ax-Grothendieck

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, complex-geometry

I have cross-posted this on Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433685/strengthening-ax-grothendieck

---

The question is simple. The Ax-Grothendieck theorem says a polynomial map $p\colon\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ that is injective is also surjective.

> Is assuming $p$ has finite fibers enough?

I can't come up with any easy counter-examples, but the proof I know using finite fields does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness' sake, here is the accepted answer from [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433760/111897):

For $n = 2$, the polynomial  $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1x_2 - 1, x_2(x_1x_2 - 1) + x_1)$ is a counterexample.